# Ubuntu 8.04 server: can't invoke at

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, linux, at

For some reason I can't use at command from an ordinary user

```
$ at
You do not have permission to use at.
```

I've checked my /etc/at.deny, it doesn't have my user there. There is no /etc/at.allow. I tried to restart atd, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running

```
$ strace at
setreuid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
setregid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
open("/etc/at.allow", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
setregid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
setreuid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
setreuid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
setregid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
open("/etc/at.deny", O_RDONLY)          = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
setregid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
setreuid32(1000, 1000)                  = 0
write(2, "You do not have permission to us"..., 38You do not have permission to use at.
) = 38
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

could show you the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Does `/etc/at.allow` exist? If it does, any users which aren't explicitly listed in it are prevented from running `at`.

Comment: no, it doesn't exist. I have an Ubuntu 9.10 to compare with here. But didn't find any differences yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions under /var/spool/cron? On my 8.04 system it is:

```
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Feb 18 08:36 atjobs
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Feb 20  2007 atspool
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. There is no /var/spool/at directory on Ubuntu, but there are /var/spool/cron/atjobs and /var/spool/cron/atspool. Both had other permissions, that working Ubuntu installation has. But still it didn't solved the problem :-(

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit the post with the correct files/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I've found a simple solution so far.

```
sudo aptitude purge at
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-standard
```

*Note: when you delete **at** package, **ubuntu-standard** is also deleted as it requires at. So installing **ubuntu-standard** again cause **at** installation too*

**Upd:**
I reproduced (unintentionally) this issue on other machine. It turned out that the real problem was in /etc/at.deny permissons! atd couldn't read the file.